# How to work with auto layout concept in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Create one app for iphone 4 inch screen in Xcode 6.1.1  develop one page successfully and run properly in iPhone 5s. and run iPhone 6 and 6+. its show the white empty page for iPhone 6 for extra height and width. how can support for all the screen in that same code.help me new for develpoment..

Comment: Your question is too broad for stackoverflow. You need to do your own research, stackoverflow is for asking how to solve specific errors, not learn a new technology / library. There are many autoLayout tutorials online, search google, study one and then come back if you have a specific issue or error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very generic question , it is a big topic at the beginning it might be a pain in the ass but you would be amazed how powerful it is when you master it , i would say that you should read a tutorial , let me suggest the following such as :

[AutoLayout tutorial](https://bradbambara.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/auto-layout-concepts-in-ios/)

it would be much useful if you learn the adaptive UI concepts as well it is amazing a link for it would be

[Adaptive Layout Tutorial](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/size-classes-with-xcode-6-one-storyboard-for-all-sizes)

When dealing with Autolayout keep in mind that a major difference between it and using the frames  is that you depend on relations between objects position and each other  rather than fixed points , try to minmize usage of constants for alignments and keep it as much as possible relative for each other at the same time make sure that each object has a constraint to calculate its width, height , top and bottom positions